# Using a regular expression to match each individual character as it's own group?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

In PHP I'm trying to match each character as its own group. Which would mimic the `str_split()`. I tried:

```
$string = '123abc456def';
preg_match_all('/(.)*/', $string, $array);
// $array = array(2) { 
//   [0]=>  array(2) { 
//      [0]=>  string(12) "123abc456def"
//      [1]=>  string(0) "" } 
//   [1]=>  array(2) { [0]=>  string(1) "f" [1]=>  string(0) "" } }
```

I was expecting something like:

```
//$array = array(2) { 
//   [0]=> string(12) "123abc456def", 
//   [1]=> array(12) { 
//       [0]=>  string(1) "1", [1]=> string(1) "2"
//       ... 
//       [10]=> string(1) "e", [11]=> string(1) "f" } }
```

The reason I want to use the regular expression instead of a `str_split()` is because the regex will be the basis of another regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The * outside the parens means you want to repeat the capturing group. (This means you will only capture the last iteration.) Try a global match of any single character, like this:

```
preg_match_all('/(.)/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Comment: You can leave the parenthesis out.

Comment: True. Bad habit of being literal with any regex I compose... :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all('/./s', $str, $matches)
```

This does also match line break characters.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

> preg_match_all('/(.)+?/', $string,
>   $array);

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if this helps for this station but you can access letters of a string like array.. so

```
<?php
$a = "hede";
print $a[0] . "\n";
print $a[1] . "\n";
print $a[2] . "\n";
print $a[3] . "\n";
?>
```

will output

h

e

d

e